# Is there a zencart module for yii2?

Tags: yii2, shopping-cart

I have website made in humhub (yii2) and now I need to make shopping cart inside that site. Is there any modules in yii2 for this task?

Comment: Have you checked this [yii2-shop](https://github.com/samdark/yii2-shop) ?

Comment: If you just need a shopping cart functionality: https://github.com/omnilight/yii2-shopping-cart

Comment: ok, i see both, but both are last commit one year ago, for now i will try Fory suggestion , thank you.